# Hashmap filtering in java lambda

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

Want a functional style filtering on two hashmap...

Say... I got a hashmap data as given map from database

```
    Map<String, Object> user=new HashMap<>();
    user.put("Name", "SomeName");
    user.put("Role", userRoles);
    //some relevant keys and value
```

The userRoles is a list of strings like below..

```
    List<String> userRoles = new ArrayList<>();
    userRoles.add("User");
    userRoles.add("Admin");
```

And the service permission from db

```
    List<String> servicePermission = new ArrayList<>();
    servicePermission.add("User");
    servicePermission.add("Public");
```

Now I want to filter with lambda... if ***any of userRoles*** exists ***in servicePermission***  list return true or return false/exception.

> Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following.

```
return ((List<String>) user.get("Role")).stream()
                           .anyMatch(servicePermisions::contains);
```

Comment: And you probably want to make your servicePermissions `List` into a `Set` because a) it doesn't make any sense to have the same permission listed more than once and b) `List.contains()` is a time sink compared to `HashSet.contains()`

Comment: @SteveK ... and the userRoles.

Comment: Yes, that too, although the `servicePermissions` being a `List` is the one that would be slowing the process down potentially since we already have to iterate through all the roles individually anyway.

Comment: @SteveK except performing a hash lookup is more expensive than iterating over two strings. ;) though a hash lookup scales far better.

Comment: I would use `user.getOrDefault("Role", Collections.emptyList()))` to avoid a potential NPE if there is no mapping, as `anyMatch` returns false with an empty stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `anyMatch` :

```
boolean match = 
    user.get("Role").stream()
                    .anyMatch(s -> servicePermission.contains(s));
```